# Phonegap app don't work with IPv6 on iPhone

Tags: ios, websocket, ipv6, phonegap

I have PhoneGap based application that uses WebSockets. It works well under Android and Windows (via Chrome) - both for IPv4 and IPv6. However, on iPhone it works with IPv4 only.

For example, if I use address "104.217.75.167" (my test server), it works on Android, Windows and iPhone. If I use "::ffff:104.217.75.167" or "::ffff:68d9:4ba7" (the same), it works on Android and Windows only, but not on iPhone.

I guess the problem is in Safari browser (WebKit) because PhoneGap engine uses it as a base of application. But I have no Mac to debug it.

The code I use is this:

```
    const ip_input = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("ipaddress");
    const ip: string = ip_input.value.replace(/\s/g, ''); // remove spaces
    const isIpV6 = ip.includes(':');
    const bracketedIp = isIpV6 ? '['+ip+']' : ip;
    const fullAddr: string = "ws://" + bracketedIp + ":44405/websocket";
    TheSocket = new WebSocket(fullAddr);
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: You're not supposed to use [IP address literals](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW23) in iOS. This is one of the problems that will cause Apple to reject the app for IPv6 incompatibility. Apple recommends you use hostnames instead.

Comment: @ Michael Hampton

Comment: @ Michael Hampton:
You are unfortunately right. But IPv4 address literals work perfectly!

I am really shocked about this. Apple says we must use IPv6, not IPv4. But on iPhone exactly IPv6 doesn't work! I guess this is Safari problem because PhoneGap uses browser engine.

Comment: IPv4 literals work but it's still a bad practice. There should not be address literals anywhere.

Comment: "_Apple says we must use IPv6, not IPv4._" That's not what Apple wants. Apple requires that your application work on on IPv6-only network, not that it cannot use IPv4. There really is a difference.

Comment: @Ron Maupin
You are right as well. I am just surprised the working on IPv6-only network doesn't work. I was expecting problems with IPv4, not with IPv6.

Comment: It looks like that is all iPhone browser's problem (tested on Safari and Yandex browser which is based on Chrome). They understand [IPv6] addresses in URLs but not in javascript websockets.